# Can't see custom CCK field in view

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, cck

I created a content type a while ago, and a view to filter it. I just added a field to that content type. When I try to add a filter to the view, the field that I just created isn't in the list. If I create new content of that type, I can see the new field, but not from the view. I deleted and recreated the field, changing the type of field, and have cleared cache. I've also tried creating another view, and still can't see that field. I can see all other custom fields, though.

Comment: A shot in the dark, but did you check the permissions of the field?

Comment: field level permissions? Where to change that?

Comment: The user permissions page if I am not mistake says who can view/edit fields per content type. /admin/people/permissions

Comment: it's the admin user that I'm using now. Also, the other fields that I can edit are in the same content type.

Comment: Came here seeking @joshmmo answer, funny enough.

Comment: I think there's a problem with views in general. I've tried creating a few content types, with other fields, and Views doesn't see any of it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the field you added a taxonomy or node reference? You may need to add a relationship to the referenced entity in order to get it to show up under the view fields.

Click "Add" beside "Relationships", and see if the entity type you are referencing is in that list... add the reference, then go back to adding fields and see if it shows up in your list.

Comment: I've tried several different kinds of fields - ideally, it would be a dropdown list. It's definitely not a reference field.

Comment: What type of field is it, and do you have many modules installed? Might be worth making a dev site to confirm operation.

Comment: it's a text field - the site is pretty well along - trying to use a dev site, and trying to recreate everything would be a major undertaking